# Knockout JS: Build a viewModel out of pre-defined Objects

Tags: javascript, object, knockout.js

I have a large XML file (converted to JSON) that consists of multiple repeating sections with the same structure. Each section has a set of identically structured attribues (XML to JSON conversion moves all attributes into an object called `myAttributes`) in addition to the section specific properties. My objective is to be able to read existing XML and generate new XML.

I tried to use the mapping plugin, put it only allows me to read XML, not generate it, plus there are multiple interdependencies between object elements.

I figured that the best way to work around this is to pre-define a set of objects that match small sections of the XML. When assembled together, these objects would be able to generate XML structure that i need. This way I can either loop though the JSON array that I generated from XML, populate objects that I pre-defined with appropriate data and append them to my viewModel (lets say 10 alerts, 3 actions, 6 metric groupings, etc). Generating XML from pre-defined objects should also be easy.

However, due to my general inexperience with both JavaScrip and KnockoutJS, I am having a very hard time figuring this one out.

```
// Main Top Level Management Module Object
function ManagementModule(data) {
    this.myAttributes = new Object();
    this.myAttributes.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    this.myAttributes.IsActive = ko.observable(data.IsActive);
    this.myAttributes.DescriptionContentType = ko.observable(data.DescriptionContentType);
    this.myAttributes.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
    // There are other object specific properties, but I omitted them for now
}

// New Alert Object. It will be deep in the hierarchy of the main top level object
// but for now i will make it top level for test purposes.
function Alert(data) {
    this.myAttributes = new Object();
    this.myAttributes.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    this.myAttributes.IsActive = ko.observable(data.IsActive);
    this.myAttributes.DescriptionContentType = ko.observable(data.DescriptionContentType);
    this.myAttributes.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
    // There are other object specific properties, but I omitted them for now
}

// View Model
function myModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.ManagementModule = ko.observableArray();
    self.Alerts = ko.observableArray();
};
var myViewModel = new myModel();
```

Then I loop through my JSON and try to append things to the view model... and this is where things do not work right. Perhaps because I misunderstand the objects...

```
$.getJSON("/getXML", function (data) {

    for (var key in data) {
        // Do something here
    }

    // This seems to work OK. There is only 1 so, I just
    // set it.
    myViewModel.ManagementModule(data['myAttributes']);

    for (var i = 0; i < data['DataGroups']['DataGroup'].length; i++) {
        var current = data['DataGroups']['DataGroup'][i];
        if(current['AlertBase']) {

             var AlertBase = current['AlertBase'];

             // There are multiple Alarts
             for (var i = 0; i < AlertBase.length; i++) {
                     myViewModel.Alerts.push(Alert(AlertBase[i].myAttributes));
             }
        }

    };
    ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);

});
```

This kinda-sorta works.... When I try to bind to it

```
<div data-bind="text: Alerts.myAttributes.Name"></div>
<div data-bind="text: ManagementModule.myAttributes.Name"></div>
```

it is not working. If i bind like this:

```
<div data-bind="text: myAttributes.Name"></div>
```

it outputs both, `myViewModel.ManagementModuleName.myAttributes.Name` and the very last one `myViewModel.Alert.myAttributes.Name` joined together.

What am I doing wrong? How can I assemble a viewModel out of multiple nested objects?

UPDATE: Just realized I was binding incorrectly, but that still produces a bunch of 
`myViewModel.ManagementModuleName.myAttributes.Name` and the very last one `myViewModel.Alert.myAttributes.Name` joined together

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Alerts()">
    <div data-bind="text: myAttributes.Name"></div>
</div>
```

And I think I solved it...

```
myViewModel = new ManagementModule(data['myAttributes']);

myViewModel.Alerts = ko.observableArray();
myViewModel.Alerts.push(new Alert(AlertBase[i].myAttributes));


<div data-bind="text: myAttributes.Name"></div><br />
<div data-bind="foreach: Alerts()">
    <div data-bind="text: myAttributes.Name"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you are referencing observableArrays as if they we observables. You need a data-bind=foreach: Alarms() in there someplace.

OK: See if this jsFiddle helps you: http://jsfiddle.net/8QVe6/

Note that I made the properties camelCased (i.e. managementModule).

Comment: thanks. realized that too on the way home in the car and updated the question. Still does not work as expected though

Comment: Thanks Steve. I got it to work, but really appreciate you taking time to fix my code and give solution. Marking as solved. Thanks again. As far as variables, I prefer camelCase myself, but they come from XML with an upper case first letter, so i have to keep it this way.